# Bounds on chromatic number of $k$-planar graphs

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, graph-drawing

A [$1$-planar graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-planar_graph) can be drawn in the
plane so that each arc is crossed at most once by another arc.
A $k$-planar graph can be drawn so that each arc is crossed at most $k$ times.

Planar graphs are $4$-colorable, and $1$-planar graphs are $6$-colorable.
($K_6$ is $1$-planar: image below from [here](http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/GraphTheory/MyGraphTheory/embedding.htm).)

 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
[image: K_6]

> What bounds are known on the colorability of $k$-planar graphs?

This has likely been studied; I just don't know the results. Thanks for pointers!

---

**Answered** by Tony Huynh and David Eppstein: The chromatic number of a $k$-planar graph is $\Theta(\sqrt{k})$.

Comment: A newer question on coloring $2$-planar graphs: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/346655/does-there-exist-2-planar-graph-with-chromatic-number-8-or-9-or-10

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pach and Tóth [proved](http://www.renyi.hu/~pach/publications/fewcrossing.pdf) that if $G$ is a $k$-planar graph (with $k \geq 1$), then

$|E(G)| \leq 4.108 \sqrt{k} |V(G)|$.

Thus, every $k$-planar graph has a vertex of degree at most $\lfloor8.216 \sqrt{k}\rfloor$. By induction, it follows that $k$-planar graphs can be coloured with $\lfloor8.216 \sqrt{k}\rfloor+1$ colours.

For $1 \leq k \leq 4$, they prove a better bound of

$|E(G)| \leq (k+3)(|V(G)|-2)$.

Thus, we can do slightly better for small values of $k$.  That is, 2-planar graphs are 10-colourable, 3-planar graphs are 12-colourable, and 4-planar graphs are 14-colourable.

For $k=3$, [Pach, Radoičic, Tardos, and Tóth](http://www.cs.bme.hu/~geza/newfew.pdf) proved an even better upper bound of

$|E(G)| \leq 5.5(|V(G)|-2)$.

Comment: Thanks, Tony! In conjunction with David's remarks, this shows that the chromatic number is $\Theta(\sqrt{k})$.

Answer (score 7):

To complement Tony Huynh's answer, something proportional to $\sqrt k$ is also a lower bound on the chromatic number: there exist $k$-planar graphs that need this many colors. In particular, if one draws a complete graph of $\Theta(\sqrt k)$ vertices by placing the vertices on a circle and drawing the edges as line segments, the resulting drawing will be $k$-planar but the complete graph will require $\Omega(\sqrt k)$ colors.

Comment: Nice lower-bound construction, David! Thanks!