# Does there exist 2-planar graph with chromatic number 8 or 9 or 10

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings, topological-graph-theory, planar-graphs

A 2-planar graph is a graph that can be drawn in the plane so that each edge is crossed at most twice. It is known that every 2-planar graph satisfies that $|E(G)|\le 5(|V(G)|-2)$. This implies that every 2-planar graph contains a vertex of degree at most 9 and thus every 2-planar is 10-colorable. On the other hand, $K_7$ is a 2-planar graph. So my question is whether there is a 2-planar graph with chromatic number 8 or 9 or 10?  Thanks for pointers!

Note the $K_8$ is not 2-planar!

Comment: Dmitry Karpov announced the proof that $\chi(G)\leqslant 9$, but this is not published yet. You may contact him directly: dvk0 at yandex dot ru

Comment: An earlier discussion of coloring $k$-planar graphs (but not helpful in answering this question) is https://mathoverflow.net/questions/168440/bounds-on-chromatic-number-of-k-planar-graphs